# How To Change Cross-Origin-Opener Settings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm building a web app using MERN and am using Google Login for my app (OAUTH-2.0). Anytime I try to login, however, the information does not log and I instead get an error Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem and how you solved it. I tried changing my index.html settings but this has not been successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what's the bug since you haven't provide the exact information but still this is the way you can setup the cors package

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        // Replace 'frontend.com' with the domain you want to block
        if (origin === 'https://frontend.com') {
            callback(new Error('Access from this domain is not allowed'));
        } else {
            callback(null, true);
        }
    }
}));
```

and if you don't want to specify the certain origin you do
`app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));`